# Dynamic SQL Pivot Without Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like below:

```
cust no int id  row no
111111  53453453623432  12345
111112  63453453623432  12346
111111  53453453623432  21234
111112  63453453623432  33347
```

and i am trying to achieve the following result below -

```
cust no int id  row no 1    row no 2
111111  53453453623432  12345   21234
111112  63453453623432  12346   33347
```

I am essentially trying to pivot the row no in Ascending order. I will note that there may be an infinite amount of ROW_NO'S for a particular customer.

I have been pulling out my hair with this one. Not sure if this requires tsql or not. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please DON'T SHOUT AT US. Fix your CAPS LOCK key. SHOUTING will not get you answers any faster, the text is more difficult to read, and it's just rude and annoying.

Comment: sorry first time on this site

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from (
    select cust_no,int_id,row_no, 
        'row_no_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by int_id 
                order by row_no) as nvarchar(10)) as colid 
    from @table) p
    pivot (min(row_no) for colid in (row_no_1,row_no_2)) pvt
```

Result is

```
cust_no int_id          row_no_1 row_no_2
111111  53453453623432  12345   21234
111112  63453453623432  12346   33347
```

Full script below,

```
declare @table table (
cust_no nvarchar(100), int_id nvarchar(100), row_no nvarchar(100) )

insert into @table
values('111111','53453453623432','12345')
,('111112','63453453623432','12346')
,('111111','53453453623432','21234')
,('111112','63453453623432','33347')

select * from (
    select cust_no,int_id,row_no, 
        'row_no_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by int_id 
                order by row_no) as nvarchar(10)) as colid 
    from @table) p
    pivot (min(row_no) for colid in (row_no_1,row_no_2)) pvt
```

Comment: Thanks abdul ... brillant

Answer (score 0):

```
                Declare @Query1 varchar(max),@Query2 varchar(max) 
                IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
                    Drop TABLE #Temp
                create table
                #Temp ([cust_no] bigint,[int_id] bigint,[row_no] bigint)

                Insert INTO #Temp([cust_no],[int_id],[row_no]) values (111111,53453453623432,12345)
                Insert INTO #Temp([cust_no],[int_id],[row_no]) values (111112,63453453623432,12346)
                Insert INTO #Temp([cust_no],[int_id],[row_no]) values (111111,53453453623432,21234)
                Insert INTO #Temp([cust_no],[int_id],[row_no]) values (111112,63453453623432,33347)
                Insert INTO #Temp([cust_no],[int_id],[row_no]) values (111111,53453453623432,33348)
                Insert INTO #Temp([cust_no],[int_id],[row_no]) values (111111,53453453623432,33349)

                IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL
                    Drop TABLE #Temp1

                    select cust_no,int_id,row_no, 
                        'row_no_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by int_id 
                                order by row_no) as nvarchar(10)) as colid 
                    INTO #Temp1 from #Temp


                      SELECT  @Query1 = COALESCE(@Query1 + ', ', '') + colid
                                    FROM #temp1 group by colid ;

                    --print @Query1


                      SET @Query2 = 'Select * from #temp1 pivot (min(row_no) for colid in (' + @Query1 + ' )) pvt'

                  --print @Query2
                  exec(@Query2)
```